# Controlling slideUp and SlideDown

Tags: jquery, slide

I'm creating an accordion menu with JQuery.
So far I could do it but only with one sublist open at a time and I need to leave as many as I want.

I need to `slideUp()` only the exactly menu I clicked not all of them...

Here is my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/gpEdoR) where you can see the code working.

As you can see, when you open one submenu you close all the rest. I know it's because  of this line of code:

```
$(".prof-list ul").slideUp();
```

I just can't find a way to do what I want... When I click on the `H3` or that specific `li` tag. How may I close only that exactly one  and leave all the rest the way it is (closed / opened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle) for current element,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prof-list h3").click(function(){
        //Slide up all the elements of the list
        //$(".prof-list ul").slideUp();// comment this
        //Slide down the elements below the H3 clicked - only if closed
        //if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) // comment this
        {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();// use slideToggle here
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPdeGQ)

Simplified code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prof-list h3").click(function(){
        //Toggle only current container's content
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this `slideToggle()` has some kind of incompatibility?

Comment: No, its like another functions available in jQuery like slideUp(), slideDown(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep only one line in your `click event` as below and remove the rest.

```
$(".prof-list h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
```

**[Pen here](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/xGByRR)**

Comment: Awesome... Thanks buddy ! Does this slideToggle() has some kind of incompatibility?

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. incompatibility? as of my knowledge **no**.. :) may be you have to check in IE for its working!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample code that you can reuse. here i added **ID for parent UL element as list**

```
var pre;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#list").find("ul").hide();

         pre = $("#list").find("ul:first");
        pre.show();

        $("#list").find("h3").each(eachItem);

    });

    eachItem = function(key, val) {

        console.log(val);

        $(val).click(function(e) {



            $(e.target).parent().find("ul").slideDown();
            pre.hide();
            pre = $(e.target).parent().find("ul");

        });

    }
```